# Trying to make a program that randomises teams acording to user input (amount of teams and names of all participants) these will then be equal in size

Tags: python, random

I need to make a program where the user inputs all students names (this is then converted into a list each name becomes an item) and y amount of teams, the program will then randomize the teams with the names of the students. Ex. The user chooses 2 teams and has 4 different students the program then spits out 2 randomized teams with 2 students in each (these cannot be the same students).

```
import random
import os

#clears the screen
os.system('cls')

#creates the list that later is filled with user input
list_name = []

temp_name = ""

#team_total is the user choosen amount of teams, this is then converted into integer
team_total = input("How many teams do you want?\n")
team_total = int(team_total)

#makes it so that all names written by the user are converted to individual list items
name = input("What are your students names?:\n")
for x in name:
    if x == " ":
        list_name.append(temp_name)
        temp_name = ""
        continue
    else:
        temp_name = temp_name + x
list_name.append(temp_name)

#using len to create varible that is equivilant to the amount of items in list_name
y = len(list_name)

#team_size is the amount of people in each team (amount of teams divided by amount of students)
team_size = (y / team_total)

print(f"There will be {team_size} per team!")




#r1 is the student in team_1 
r1=random.randint(0,int(y))
team_a = (list_name[r1])

#r2 is the student in team_b (this also makes it so that r2 cant be the same as r1)
r2=random.randint(0,int(y))
while r2 == r1:
    r2 = random.randint(0,(y))
    r2=random.randint(0,int(y))
team_b = (list_name[r2])
```

This is how far I've gotten, I am completely stuck so help would be appriciated!

Comment: As a side note, you may replace your `for x in name: ...` loop with `list_name = temp_name.split()` - more robust and more idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

`list.pop()` is an easy way here:

```
import random

players = ["Anton", "Bernd", "Charlie", "Dickins", "Eugine", "Franco"]
teams = {}
num_teams = 5   # This is what you would ask the user

def run():
    for team_number in range(num_teams):
        teams.update({team_number: []})

    while len(players) > 0:
        for team_number, team in teams.items():
             if len(players) == 0:
                break
             index_to_remove = random.randint(0, len(players) - 1)

             team.append(players.pop(index_to_remove))

    print(teams)
```

You have a player list `players = ["Anton", "Bernd", "Charlie", "Dickins", "Eugine", "Franco"]`

A `teams` dictionary. This dictionary you populate with the amount of teams (empty lists `[]`) that you need:

```
for team_number in range(num_teams):
       teams.update({team_number: []})
```

After that you go over each team in the dictionary, `pop()` a random player from your `players` list into that team.
Repeat this process until you have no more players in the `players` list.

If you have more players than can be equally divided among the teams, the first teams in the dictionary will have a higher amount of players than the later teams. If you insist on equal teams, you need to insert a check that the players can be equally divided among all teams. If that check fails the program aborts:

```
len(players) % num_teams == 0
```

Sample output for 3 teams:

```
How many teams do you want?
3
{0: ['Anton', 'Dickins'], 1: ['Eugine', 'Franco'], 2: ['Bernd', 'Charlie']}
```

additional information:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your players (a list of names) you can use *random.shuffle()* to rearrange the list into pseudo-random order. You can then access that list sequentially. For example:

```
from random import shuffle as SHUFFLE

nteams = int(input('How many teams? '))
players = input('Enter player names separated by space: ').split()
SHUFFLE(players)
ts = len(players) // nteams
teams = {i//ts: players[i:i+ts] for i in range(0, len(players), ts)}
print(teams)
```

**Example:**

```
How many teams? 3
Enter players names separated by space: john david paul peter clive boris fred
{0: ['paul', 'boris'], 1: ['john', 'david'], 2: ['clive', 'fred'], 3: ['peter']}
```

**Note:**

Note what happens when the number of players is not exactly divisible by the number of teams

Comment: thank you!, this really helped but could you explain to me how:                                        
 teams = {i//ts: players[i:i+ts] for i in range(0, len(players), ts)}  works i dont really understand this line.

Comment: @LuisWettre That's a dictionary comprehension. I suggest a Google search for that phrase